# Complex LED drivers/circuits

Tags: led, pwm, gate-driving

Throughout my travels I've seen these very complex circuits that incorporate ICs for "i.e. dimming applications" that are included in designs with buck boost converters, etc. What makes LED driving circuitry so complex?? Is it because you are driving some kind of gate driver and Control algorithm for pwm? It's usually a power requirement rather than a control requirement right?

Comment: Quick, you don't have much time. Elaborate. In what context? How many LEDs? Power rating? Etc.

Comment: What do you find painful in driving LEDs? Can you be more specific? Do you have a specific problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: If no elaboration is given, this may be flagged considering as it stands right now, it is primarily opinion based.  A person might be better at one aspect of it than others are and thus think it is more difficult for some other reason

Comment: What "complex circuits"? Reference an example, or something? This question is just "I've seen a thing and drawn some conclusion on it. What do you think?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pain because PWM requires precise timer control.  To get around that, semiconductor companies offer parts with hardware PWM, such as the TLC5940 from TI.  Although those features are expensive to make in hardware, and to avoid those costs in production, designers of a device will choose to implement PWM in software which comes back around to the precise timer control.

It really depends on your application as to whether the worst part is in regards to the control algorithm or the power delivery.  I would venture to say in hobbyist applications or applications that aren't targeted at lighting, its the control algorithm.  But if it is in very professional displays, for sure the power delivery.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the application and what you are using as a control unit, as well as the type of IC's you are referring to. If you refer to the drivers that use a communication protocol like, let's say, SPI, I find those IC's very useful when you have many LEDs (the "many" depends on the control unit as well)

For example, if you are using a micro-controller in your aplication which you want to use to drive the LEDs, the PWM might not be a problem since most devices include the necessary hardware to handle it; however, you may not have all I/O pins available with PWM outputs. And, if your application is simple, I don't think it would be a better option to find a micro-controller with more I/O pins since it would probably increase the memory size and other features, and hence, its cost. In my experience, the best solution is one of those drivers you mention because I have at most used 4 of my I/O pins (spi protocol) to control any number of LEDs, and the control algorithm is way simpler and saves a lot of time.

So, the total number of LEDs you are using is also a critical fact to consider.